# [INSTALL_FAILED_OLDER_SDK: Requires newer sdk version #33 (current version is #31)]

Tags: flutter, dart, sdk, build.gradle

[image: main.dart code and Error]

[image: build.gradle]

[image: build.gradle]

Installation failed on android physical device.
While running initial code it runs properly but after adding webview_flutter package it requires newer sdk version.
I did following things but still getting same problem.

In build.gradle

......
android{
compileSDKVersion 33
....
defaultConfig{
minSDKVersion 33
targetSDKVersion 33
....
}
}

Comment: It's probably that your phone SDK version is lower than 33 since you set minSdkVersion to 33.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is due to android SDK version mismatch between your app and the target device (i.e. real phone or emulator).

From your case it seems like your app is built with SDK version 31 and you are trying to run it on a device which supports version 30 resulting in the issue. TO fix this either downgrade the your app's SDK need to 30 or run it on a newer device that supports SDK 31.